# Replacing ordinary compareTo ints with a LessThan/GreaterThan/Equal objects

Tags: scala

I'm currently learning Scala.  Since I don't like to use `Int` for the result of a comparison (such as `Ordered.compareTo` does), I tried to come up with a way to replace it.  This is what I came up with:

```
sealed trait ComparisonResult

case object LessThan extends ComparisonResult
case object GreaterThan extends ComparisonResult
case object Equal extends ComparisonResult

object ComparisonImplicits {
  implicit def Int2ComparisonResult(value: Int) = value match {
    case v if v < 0 => LessThan
    case v if v > 0 => GreaterThan
    case _ => Equal
  }
}
```

Then I can write things like

```
val comparison: ComparisonResult = a compareTo b
comparison match {
  case LessThan => ...
  case GreaterThan => ...
  case Equal => ...
}
```

Unfortunately, I have to store the `Int` in a `val` of type `ComparisonResult` for this to work.  E.g. `if (a.compareTo(b) == LessThan)` doesn't work.

Is there a better or more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at [`scalaz` `Order[A]`](http://eed3si9n.com/ja/scalaz-cheat-sheet): `1 ?|? 2` => `res0: scalaz.Ordering = LT`.

Comment: @senia Thanks.  It seems `scalaz` is a library I'll want to use in any project that uses Scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in Senia's comment, i.e. to use `scalaz` seems to be the best one.

`Scalaz` allows to compare using `a |?| b` and match the result against e.g. `Ordering.LT`.

In addition, it defines operators so that you can write `if (a lt b) ...`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get around this using your code. The compiler can't infer that an implicit conversion should be applied in this place, as the `Int` returned by `compareTo` defines `==` for any type. If there is no missing method, the compiler is not going to search for an implicit conversions.

What you could do instead:

```scala
implicit class ComparableInt(val i: Int) extends AnyVal{
  def isLessThan(other: Int) = i < other
  def isGreaterThan(other: Int) = i > other
}

if( 3 isLessThan 4) ":D" else ":("
```

Comment: This will only compare ints.  Doesn't seem so useful to have an implicit class for each type that you want to compare.  You want to be able to use the natural ordering of types that have one.  While this can be adapted to meet that requirement, `scalaz` already provides these comparison operators, so it seems the answer in senia's comment was best.